# Writing pointers to the address of GPIO out pin

Tags: c, embedded, gpio

Absolute noob to embedded system. Right now I am trying to program a device called `nRF52832` in `C`. I know that the base address for the `GPIO` is `0x50000000` and the offset for the OUT register is `0x504`. How do I create pointers to the addresses of the GPIO OUT and print the address?

Do I do

```
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_BASE = (unsigned int*) 0x50000000;
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_OUT = GPIO_BASE + 0x504; ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that pointer arithmetic is always done in the units of the pointer base type.

That means the expression `GPIO_BASE + 0x504` will add a byte-offset of `0x504 * sizeof *GPIO_BASE`, which is `0x504 * sizeof(int)` (which on most systems will be an offset of 5136 bytes, not 1284 bytes).

If you want to add an offset of `0x504` *bytes* you need to divide it by the size of the pointer base type:

```
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_OUT = GPIO_BASE + (0x504 / sizeof *GPIO_BASE);
```

Except this problem your code is correct, and a very common way to access hardware registers.

Comment: `GPIO_BASE + (0x504 / sizeof *GPIO_BASE);` is gibberish though, you would never write code like that in the calling application. The offset should be calculated inside macros and definitely not in run-time, as in this example.

Comment: I think something like `#define GPIO_OFFSET(x, y) (unsigned int *) ((char *) (x) + (char *) (y))` and then simply `volatile unsigned  int* GPIO_OUT = GPIO_OFFSET(GPIO_BASE, 0x504)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I do
>
> ```
> volatile unsigned int* GPIO_BASE = (unsigned int*) 0x50000000;
> volatile unsigned int* GPIO_OUT = GPIO_BASE + 0x504;
> ```

No, you don't. That would mean that the address gets calculated in run-time, because the `volatile` qualifier means that the program has to update the variable in run-time whenever it is used.

This is what you should do instead:

```
// assuming 32 bit registers and 0x504 being the offset in bytes
#define GPIO_BASE 0x50000000u
#define GPIO_OUT  (*(volatile uint32_t*)(GPIO_BASE + 0x504u))
#define GPIO_X    (*(volatile uint32_t*)(GPIO_BASE + 0x508u)) // some other related register 

...
GPIO_OUT = something;
```

In this example, the register addresses are calculated at compile-time, which is the only correct way of doing it.

By de-referencing the address inside the macro, we can now use `GPIO_OUT` almost as if it was an ordinary variable.

It does however seem unlikely that a GPIO peripheral has hundreds of memory-mapped registers, so the value `0x504` is strange.

---

Also please note that using the default C types like `int` and `char` in embedded systems is naive. These types come with various portability problems and also have various forms of poorly-defined behavior associated with them. Professional systems only use the types from `stdint.h` and never anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_BASE = (unsigned int*) 0x50000000;
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_OUT = GPIO_BASE + 0x504;
```

If `offset` for the `OUT` register is `0x504` bytes away from `BASE`, then you need to typecast `GPIO_BASE` to `char *`

```
volatile unsigned int* GPIO_OUT = ((char *)GPIO_BASE) + 0x504;
```

Otherwise all ok.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you elaborate on why do we need (char *)? I thought you can just add hex address

Comment: @user3084686 It is because of pointer arithmetic. Please read about it online.

Answer (score 0):

Because of pointer arithmetic, the value of the pointer GPIO_OUT will be GPIO_BASE + (0x504 * sizeof(int)). If sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, you will get pointer to 0x50000000 + (0x504 * 4) = 0x50001410, while the actual address for the OUT register is 0x50000504. You can type-cast the pointer to unsigned char* or better yet use macro.

#define GPIO_BASE 0x50000000

#define GPIO_OUT GPIO_BASE + 0x504

volatile unsigned int* gpio_out = GPIO_OUT;

Comment: `volatile unsigned int* gpio_out = GPIO_OUT; ` isn't valid C, however.